# How to solve 3SAT using brute force and N.D.M

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I have been studying and trying to solve 3SAT using brute force and N.D.M but could not do so. can anyone please explain these to me in detail and tell me basic algorithm to solve 3SAT using brute force and N.D.M ? thanks

Comment: Which N.D.M. are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

One Brute Force solution is simply to try all possible inputs. So to try and solve (A|B)&(~A|C)&(~B)&(~C) try 000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111 where xyz is A=x,B=y,C=z.

If by NDM you mean Non-Deterministic Machine as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-deterministic_Turing_machine there are different ways of thinking about this. One is to suppose that you have to pay for computing time, but there is a loophole in the contract, where if you try all possible inputs you only get charged for the longest run of these tries - all the others are free.